# Error at driver install: File not found

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I have manually chosen an INF-file to use to install drivers in Windows 7 professional. In the middle of the installation process, I get an error message that a certain file could not be found, with no further information about filename, etc. Is there any way to find more detailed information about which files could not be found?